# Simplify $x^{\frac{2}{3}}+3x^{\frac{1}{3}}-2=0$ to $x^2 +45x-8=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics

Simplify ($x^{\frac{2}{3}}+3x^{\frac{1}{3}}-2=0$) to ($x^2 +45x-8=0$)

These two equations have the same solutions.

If given the first equation how would you go about simplifying such that you end up with the quadratic form ?

I tried cubing the first expression but it got really messy.

Comment: They are not same.

Comment: They have the same roots though.

Comment: No, they don't.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? It seems I'm misunderstanding something. Does $x=\frac{-45 \pm \sqrt{2057}}{2}$ satisfy both equations? If not then which one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cubing is not a mess. Look here:
$$x^{2/3}+3 x^{1/3}=2$$
cubing both sides
$$\left(x^{2/3}+3 x^{1/3}\right)^3=8$$
Expand:
$$27 x^{4/3}+9 x^{5/3}+x^2+27 x=8$$
Collect $x$ between (among?) the first two terms:
$$9 \left(x^{2/3}+3 x^{1/3}\right) x+x^2+27 x=8$$
Inside the parenthesis there is the left side of the given equation, which is 2
$$9 \cdot 2 \cdot x+x^2+27 x=8$$
Rearrange and get the second equation
$$x^2+45 x-8=0$$

The two equations have the same *real* solutions. Usually cubing an equation creates fake solutions, as in the following example:
$$x=1$$
has the solution $x=1$, while
$$x^3=1$$
has three solutions, the cubic roots of 1
$$1,\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i\sqrt{3} \right),\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+i\sqrt{3} \right)$$
Two of them are fake solutions.

Comment: Not fake solutions.  Additional solutions of the cubed equation.

Comment: Which do not solve the original equation, so they have to be removed. I think "fake" isn't that far off.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of $y^2+3y-2=0$. So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha+\beta=-3 \\
\alpha \beta =-2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now calculate the equation whose roots are $\alpha^3$ and $\beta^3$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha^3+\beta^3&=&(\alpha+\beta)^3-3\alpha\beta(\alpha+\beta)&=&-45 \\
\alpha^3 \beta^3 &=&(\alpha\beta)^3&=&-8.
\end{eqnarray*}
So $x^2+45x-8=0$ is the equation with roots $\alpha^3$ and $\beta^3$. $x$ and $y$ are linked by $y=x^3$ and $y=x^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Comment: Thanks but that is how I came across this situation in the first place. I want to sub $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ in for $y$ and then using algebra simplify that expression to $x^2 +45x-8=0$. Any ideas?